# Magento 2 : How to add pages to custom tabs in admin panel

Tags: magento2, admin-panel

i have created custom tabs in magento 2 and i want to add pages to custom tabs and get values from database from custom tables, this is what i have done..
[image]
but dont know what to do next. how to add more options and get data from custom table.

Comment: refer this link it is an youtube video May be it is use full to you [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=89--bE3bMdE&list=PLEJnCrHZoEgQd1Sn9S_5LkJgZ91EWH5VX&index=18](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=89--bE3bMdE&list=PLEJnCrHZoEgQd1Sn9S_5LkJgZ91EWH5VX&index=18)